# Pick color from a pixel in Photoshop cc 2017

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, pixels

How can I pick a color from a pixel in Photoshop cc 2017?

Here is my program view:

[image]

Comment: You are learning Photoshop through SuperUser :D

Comment: @IvanKuckir, yeah. (x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eyedropper tool on the left works fine in the situation.

Though note that the eyedropper has sample size, averaging options at the top - so you want Point Sample, rather than a matrix sample.

[image]